# why can I manipulate UI and access database all in the same thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

Just discovered gap in my threads understanding.I have following function which saves some results to database and leaves the activity:

```
private fun leave() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            prepareForSaving()
            println("thread:${Thread.currentThread()}")
            gameData.save.id = JigsawDatabase(this@GameActivity).savesDao().upsert(gameData.save).toInt()
            val resIntent = Intent()
            val res=Gson().toJson(result)
            resIntent.putExtra("gameResult",res)
            setResult(0, resIntent)
            finish()
        }
}
```

From one side `println` prints `thread:Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main]` saying its worker thread.But I still can access UI as `finish()` works fine.Totally confused.
UPD:
I got exception when change `GlobalScore` to my viewModel's coroutineScope:

```
private fun leave() {
    model.viewModelScope.launch {
    gameData.save.id = 
    JigsawDatabase(this@GameActivity).savesDao().upsert(gameData.save).toInt()// throws Cannot access database on the main thread
    ...
    finish()
    }
}
```

What interesting even if I specify context as `model.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` it still can access UI.This makes no sense for me

Comment: `finish()` can be called from any thread AFAIK. Note that using `GlobalScope` is a code smell &mdash; that is mostly for book examples and blog posts. Usually, there is a better `CoroutineScope` to use.

Comment: I tried to set alpha of one of the button - works as well.

Comment: `Is there still only one UI thread on android?` yes. And on iOS, Windows, macOS, and Linux. Very few attempted multi-threaded UI. As far as I know, It didn't do well, and here we are.

Comment: What dispatcher is your viewodelScope set to run on?

Comment: I think I could formulate question differently like `why can I manipulate UI and access database all in the same thread?`

Comment: @Rafa:I guess its default one. I didn't specify it

Comment: @undefined I've added an explanation as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**
There are hard checks on Android for accessing things that shouldn't be done on a UI thread, but there aren't many hard checks for things that shouldn't be done on a Worker thread.

**Explanation**

A couple of things here. In regards to coroutines, if you use the `GlobalScope` or any scope really, without specifying what dispatcher it'll run on, it will run on the `Dispatcher.Default` which is the computation thread.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    // This is why you print thread:Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] here
    println("thread:${Thread.currentThread()}")
}
```

Now on the worker thread can indeed access/update your data base

```
gameData.save.id = JigsawDatabase(this@GameActivity).savesDao().upsert(gameData.save).toInt()
```

And like you mention, you are also updating the UI where you call `finish()` and aren't getting a crash.

This is because **not all methods (most view methods actually don't check for this) have a check to make sure they're not being accessed from the main thread**. Only a few things check for that.

Take live data's `setValue` method as an example of something that **does**.

```
@MainThread
protected void setValue(T value) {
    assertMainThread("setValue");
    mVersion++;
    mData = value;
    dispatchingValue(null);
}

private static void assertMainThread(String methodName) {
    if (!ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().isMainThread()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot invoke " + methodName + " on a background"
                + " thread");
    }
}
```

This actually explicitly checks to make sure that you are calling this update on the `MainThread` instead of the worker thread, and is the check that most UI elements don't have. They may just fail in some way that's hard to debug at runtime.

**Getting an exception when calling data base**

When you switched to your `viewModel` scope, you probably had it set to `Dispatchers.Main`.

At that point if you wanted to call something that explicitly had a check to make sure it was being called on a worker thread (like a Room database), you would get this crash.

```
Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long periods of time.
```

Comment: Indeed looks like safety checks are only inside methods that modify display list.I got `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` exception when added removeView call.This makes sense.Thanks!

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.